# Join dataframes R and repeat values

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I want to join two datasets and add a new vector with values to all rows. The datasets contain different numbers of rows and where some of the values in the different rows don´t match, I still want the value of the new vector to be added.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A"),
  RH = c(85, 90, 95, 80, 85, 90),
  f = c(NA, NA, 92, 23, 14, 7)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "A"),
  RH = c(95, 80),
  f = c(92, 23),
  p3 = c(12, 32)
)
```

and this is what I want the result to be

```r
wanted <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A"),
  RH = c(85, 90, 95, 80, 85, 90),
  f = c(NA, NA, 92, 23, 14, 7),
  p3 = c(12, 12, 12, 32, 32, 32)
)
```

I have tried different variants of "join", for example `left_join(df1,df2)` but it does not give the desired result

Comment: Maybe `merge(df1, df2[c(1,4)])` ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the `left_join()` function from the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) package.

I'm subsetting the `df2` dataframe so that only contains the column that matches the one from `df1` (`material`) and the one you want to add (`p3`).

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A"),
  RH = c(85, 90, 95, 80, 85, 90),
  f = c(NA, NA, 92, 23, 14, 7)
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "A"),
  RH = c(95, 80),
  f = c(92, 23),
  p3 = c(12, 32)
)
wanted <- data.frame(
  material = c("D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "A"),
  RH = c(85, 90, 95, 80, 85, 90),
  f = c(NA, NA, 92, 23, 14, 7),
  p3 = c(12, 12, 12, 32, 32, 32)
)

# Subset df2 to keep only material and p3 columns,
# makes joining more straightforward
df2_selected <- select(df2, material, p3)

result <- left_join(df1, df2_selected, by = "material")
result
#>   material RH  f p3
#> 1        D 85 NA 12
#> 2        D 90 NA 12
#> 3        D 95 92 12
#> 4        A 80 23 32
#> 5        A 85 14 32
#> 6        A 90  7 32

identical(wanted, result)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note: this approach assumes that the `p3` column in `df2` only depends on the `material`. You can combine on multiple columns as well by modifying the `by =` argument of `left_join()`. See the [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) for more details.